# Is there a better way to find the patch of image which makes a neuron fire for a CNN in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, visualization

Given a trained TensorFlow CNN model, for image classification into 5 classes , I want to find the neuron in the last convolution layer that has maximum activation (in case of same highest value for multiple neurons, any one can be taken or all of them combined can be taken, in my specific context it does not matter much). Then I want to trace this neuron back to the original image, and find the patch that caused this neuron to fire(draw a small box around it ). As shown in this [Youtube video](https://youtu.be/nBxy_vzmO_M?t=185).

For example here is the architecture of one of my CNN model

```
USE_BIAS = True

arch1 = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Conv2D(8, 11, strides=4, padding='valid', activation='relu', input_shape=(224, 224, 3), use_bias=USE_BIAS),
    keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(3, strides=2),

    keras.layers.Conv2D(16, 5, strides=1, padding='valid', activation='relu', use_bias=USE_BIAS),
    keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(3, strides=2),

    keras.layers.Flatten(),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu', use_bias=USE_BIAS),
    keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='softmax', use_bias=USE_BIAS)
])
```

After I compile and fit this model, I do one forward pass on one image ,I want to find the neuron, say N , in the *second* `Conv2D` layer , which has the highest output and then trace back to the `MaxPooling2D` before this and find which neurons are connected to N (i.e N is the maximum of what patch ), then trace back that  patch to first `Conv2D`, and then to the original image.

How can this be done?

EDIT :
I have sort of made this work for my special case by using two functions:

```
def perception_calc(prev_size,current_params,neuron_coordinates,cutoff = False):#calculates the receptive field of the neurons in the current layer
    #prev_size is a tuple of size 2 , current_params is a tuple of size 2
    #prev_size is the size of the previous layer and current_params is the stride and kernel size of the current layer
    #TODO : remove `prev_size` as a param; prev_size is not needed?

    ans = set() #set of coordinates of neurons in the conv layer which are in the receptive field
    stride = current_params[0]#tuple of size 2
    kernel_size = current_params[1]#tuple of size 2
    x_max_ = prev_size[0]#redundant?
    y_max_ = prev_size[1]#redundant?
    for i in neuron_coordinates:#reverse calculation
        x = i[0]
        y = i[1]
        x_min = x*stride[0]
        x_max = x_min + kernel_size[0]
        y_min = y*stride[1]
        y_max = y_min + kernel_size[1]
        for i in range(x_min,x_max):
            for j in range(y_min,y_max):
                ans.add((i,j)) #redundant calculation TODO: optimise?
    return ans
```

```
#find the coordinates of the neuron which is maximally activated
#trace back to original image
#original image is rgb,so it has 3 channels , handle this carefully
#draw a rectangle around the region of interest
#for best arch
def find_max_activation(image,best_arch):
    layers = [layer.output for layer in best_arch.layers]
    activation_model = keras.models.Model(inputs=best_arch.input, outputs=layers)
    f_map = activation_model.predict(image,verbose = 0)
    #find the index of last conv layer
    last_conv_index = 0
    for i in range(len(layers)):
        if 'conv' in layers[i].name:
            last_conv_index = i
    #find the value of the max activation neuron
    max_activation = np.max(f_map[last_conv_index][0])
    #find all the neurons which have the max activation value, put their indices in a list
    max_activation_indices = np.where(f_map[last_conv_index][0] == max_activation)
    #find the coordinates of the max activation neurons
    max_activation_coordinates = []
    for i in range(len(max_activation_indices[0])):
        max_activation_coordinates.append((max_activation_indices[0][i],max_activation_indices[1][i]))

    #find the receptive field of the max activation neuron
    square_coordinates = None
    #start from the last conv layer and go backwards
    n_coord = max_activation_coordinates
    for i in range(last_conv_index,0,-1):
        strides = best_arch.layers[i].get_config()['strides']
        try:
            kernel_size = best_arch.layers[i].get_config()['kernel_size']
        except:
            kernel_size = best_arch.layers[i].get_config()['pool_size']
        params = (strides,kernel_size)
        prev_size = f_map[i-1][0].shape

        n_coord = perception_calc(prev_size,params,n_coord)

        if i == 1:
            square_coordinates = n_coord
    #find the coordinates of the max activation neuron in the original image
    #the original image is of size 224x224
    #the image is rgb,so it has 3 channels
    image_coordinates = perception_calc((224,224),[(4,4),(11,11)],square_coordinates,cutoff = False)#as first layer is same for all CNNs (so hardcoded)
    #draw a rectangle around the region of interest
    sq_top_left = (min(image_coordinates)[0],min(image_coordinates)[1])
    sq_bottom_right = (max(image_coordinates)[0],max(image_coordinates)[1])
    image = image.numpy().squeeze()
    image = (image*255).astype('uint8')
    #draw rectangle
    cv2.rectangle(image,sq_top_left,sq_bottom_right,(255,255,255),2)

    #display image
    display(PIL.Image.fromarray(image, mode='RGB'))
```

but this only works for this special case of architecture, is there a way to trace back the path of neuron in the general case or perhaps a better way to do this?

EDIT2: removed `print` statements